# why pip install module in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

Tags: python

I want to install `easydict` module for python2.7 and I use the following command:

```
sudo pip install easydict
```

and I find the easydict module is installed in the python3 dir:

```
Downloading/unpacking easydict
  Downloading easydict-1.6.zip
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-hdy25apc/easydict/setup.py) egg_info for package easydict

Installing collected packages: easydict
  Running setup.py install for easydict

  Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for easydict
Successfully installed easydict
Cleaning up...
sudo pip install easydict
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): easydict in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Why does this happen? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: my OS is : ubuntu16.04

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system path. If system path has path of pip binary or python binary of 3.x prior to the path of 2.x versions. Then 3.x takes preference over 2.x

Please re-arrange your system path to have 2.x paths before 3.x paths

Comment: `kang@herakles:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Can you please tell the locations of both python 2.7 pip and python 3.x pip

Comment: Maybe it is the reason:`kang@herakles:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip kang@herakles:~$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
kang@herakles:~$ pip2 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
`

Comment: So that means that I should use `pip2` instead of `pip` to install python2.7 module next time?

Comment: But I tried to use `pip2 install easydict Downloading/unpacking easydict
  Downloading easydict-1.6.zip
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-haG8mI/easydict/setup.py) egg_info for package easydict
    
Installing collected packages: easydict
  Running setup.py install for easydict
    
  Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for easydict
Successfully installed easydict
Cleaning up...
` And I try to locate the `easydict` by `locate easydict`  It shows:

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/easydict` But not in the dir of python2.7

Comment: Strange, first uninstall easydict, then Try to rename pip in 3.5 to some other name for time being. Then try installing once again, this time it should find the 2.7 pip only

Comment: Other way add /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages to the system path at the start

Answer (score 0):

Your pip is pointing to python3, To change the pip pointing to python2 do the following

First remove python pip

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

make python3 to point python 2.7

```
alias python3=python
```

now if you type python3 in terminal you can see python 2.7 showing up

Then install python-pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

If you type pip you can see pip pointing to python 2.7

now point python3 to  python3

```
alias python3=python3
```

Comment: doubtful solution, there is a pip for Python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the pip3, you can use which find where is the pip

```
#which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

maybe you can find the pip2 or pip2.7 in the same dir

```
#pip2 -V
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

so you should use pip2 to install module